# Checking if my user button on stm32 is functioning or not

Tags: button, stm32, stm32f4discovery

this is my first time of asking a question in stackoverflow, sorry if my english is not really good. I hope this is a good start.

I am currently trying to use my stm32's key button/ user button (i mean the one button which already included on it in buying written "key") and i want to use the button to do some project. I did some research and found the key button is on pin A0, so i labelled it to **BUTTON**. So i try to check if the button is functioning using this code:

**on private variable section**

```c
int a; //variable declare
```

**on while section**

```c
while (1){
 a = 0
 if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(BUTTON_GPIO_Port, BUTTON_Pin)){
          a = 1;
      } else {
          a = 0;
      }
}
```

i'm expecting that when i debug the code and then see the live variable, i will find that variable "a" is gonna turn into 1 when i press the key button, but it is not working as i expected. The variable "a" is still on 0 whatever i do.

im kinda desperate, please help, i appreciate all of the answer :D.

Comment: You need to debounce. How the button is connected? The rest is OK but the most correct way of connecting the button is keep it high when not pressed and when pressed connect to the ground. It is because uC can sink more than source.

Comment: thank you so much for your comment, i will look forward how the button is connected on my stm32.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `a = 0;` every time around the loop. It might briefly be set to 1 if the button is pressed, but then it will be set back to zero.

Also, the compiler may well detect that the variable `a` is not actually used for anything, so it might just optimize out the setting of `a`.

Lastly, `HAL_GPIO_ReadPin()` can return `GPIO_PIN_RESET` or `GPIO_PIN_SET`. So you should test that it is one of those.

Try this:

```
volatile int a = 0; // Tell compiler not to optimize out setting of 'a'

while (1) {
    // No need to set 'a' to zero here
    if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(BUTTON_GPIO_Port, BUTTON_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_SET){
        a = 1;
    } else {
        a = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. i tried to understand your suggestion and it really increase my knowledge. Sadly it doesnt solve my problem. I guess the mistake is on the button circuit of my stm, i will look forward to it

Comment: @BDzack I presume that the pin in question has been configured (e.g. in CubeIDE) as an input?

Comment: right. the pin has been configured as an input. By the way, I did some research about my stm, which is stm32f401CCU6. And i found that my stm has no user key button included in pin A0, but i wonder why there's userkey button is available but no pin connected to it? if you know the answer please let me know. TIA

Comment: @BDzack Is this a custom board, or is it a devkit provided by someone else? Can you tell us exactly what you have? I'm confused that you said there is a button marked "key" but it is not connected to A0? What is it connected to? Do you have a schematic or user manual for your board?

Comment: it is a devkit provided with serial name stm32F401CCU6, i will give you the link of schematic of my board since i cannot share picture here https://os.mbed.com/media/uploads/hudakz/blackpill_f401cc.png

I found it aint connected to A0 since i saw  the schematic of other serial named STM32F411CEU6 which has this schematic 
https://os.mbed.com/media/uploads/hudakz/blackpill-pinout.png

Comment: It's not easy to find information about these boards online, but I tracked down a [schematic](https://stm32-base.org/assets/pdf/boards/original-schematic-STM32F401CCU6_WeAct_Black_Pill_V1.2.pdf) for something that looks like it might be your board. The `key` button is connected to `PA0`. Here is the [main page](https://stm32-base.org/boards/STM32F401CCU6-WeAct-Black-Pill-V1.2.html) for that board. Is this what you have?

Comment: i believe that is my board. Also. how you know the key button is connected to PA0 because i dont see it is explained in the pages?

Comment: Actually, maybe the button isn't connected to PA0 after all. I'm sure I saw a schematic where it was though. Maybe there are different versions of the board.

Comment: i guess so. The button probably isn't connected to PA0 and the key button on my board is just a gimmick-. Thank you for your help..